# Finding available drive space of databases stored on a LUN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a multitude of databases whose files are stored on their own individual mount points in a drive

```
(ex. Z:\dbname_db\dbname_db.mdf and Z:\dbname_log\dbname_log.ldf)
```

What I'm looking for is a way to find the available free space of the mount point.

```
    EXEC xp_cmdshell 'fsutil volume diskfree Z:\dbname_db'
```

But the service isn't running as administrator so fsutil will not work.

How would I go about doing this, is a stored procedure the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xp_fixeddrives will not display information for mount points, only normal fixed drives.

The following link has a CLR procedure that will use a Performance Counter to return the capacity and free space of a mount point.

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/tarad/archive/2007/12/18/60435.aspx

Answer (score 1):

HI,
See the below script, whic will disply total size and free space of Fxied and mount volumes. To run this sxcript Enable WMIC(go to DOS type WMIC, which will instal WMIC first time) and XP_CMDShell.

```
SET ARITHIGNORE ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

DECLARE @dsize VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(500)

SET @sql = 'xp_cmdshell ''fsutil volume diskfree ' --+'D:'''+''

CREATE TABLE #Dletter (
    Drive VARCHAR(50),
    )

CREATE TABLE #Size (Sinfo VARCHAR(250))

CREATE TABLE #DriveInfo (
    Drive VARCHAR(30),
    TotalSize REAL,
    Freesize REAL
    )

--set @x='xp_cmdshell''wmic volume get capacity,caption,freespace'''
INSERT INTO #Dletter
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'wmic volume where drivetype="3" get caption'

SET ROWCOUNT 1

DELETE
FROM #Dletter

SET ROWCOUNT 0

DELETE
FROM #Dletter
WHERE drive IS NULL
    OR len(drive) < 4

UPDATE #dletter
SET drive = replace(drive, ' ', '')

--delete from #Dletter where Drive like'R:\%'
--delete from #Capacity where Dcapacity is null or len(Dcapacity)<15 
--delete from #dletter where
-- convert(int,substring(drive,len(drive)-1,len(drive)))=5
--SELECT Row_Number() OVER (order by Drive asc) as RowNumber,drive from #Dletter
DECLARE @dv VARCHAR(30)

DECLARE dx CURSOR
FOR
SELECT *
FROM #dletter

OPEN dx

FETCH NEXT
FROM dx
INTO @dv

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + @dv + ''''

    --  print @sql
    INSERT INTO #Size
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

    DELETE
    FROM #size
    WHERE sinfo IS NULL
        OR sinfo LIKE 'Total # of avail free bytes  :%'

    --select Drive from #dletter
    --insert into #DriveInfo(Drive,TotalSize,Freesize)
    SELECT @dv AS Drive,
        convert(REAL, substring(sinfo, isnull(charindex(':', sinfo), 0) + 2, len(isnull(sinfo, 0)))) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 AS Size
    INTO #rama
    FROM #size
    ORDER BY 2 ASC

    DECLARE @d VARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @s REAL
    DECLARE @cntr INT

    SET @cntr = 1

    DECLARE x CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM #rama
    ORDER BY 2 DESC

    OPEN x

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM x
    INTO @d,
        @s

    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @cntr = 1
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Driveinfo (
                Drive,
                Totalsize
                )
            VALUES (
                @d,
                @s
                )
                --print convert(char,@cntr)+' '+convert(varchar,@d)+'TotalSize:'+convert(varchar, @s)
        END

        IF @cntr = 2
        BEGIN
            UPDATE #DriveInfo
            SET Freesize = @s
            WHERE drive = @d
                --print convert(char,@cntr)+' '+convert(varchar,@d)+'FreeSize:'+convert(varchar, @s)
        END

        FETCH NEXT
        FROM x
        INTO @d,
            @s

        SET @cntr = @cntr + 1
    END

    CLOSE x

    DEALLOCATE x

    DROP TABLE #rama

    DELETE
    FROM #size

    SET @Cntr = 1

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM dx
    INTO @dv

    --print @sql
    SET @sql = 'xp_cmdshell ''fsutil volume diskfree ' --+'D:'''+''
END

CLOSE dx

DEALLOCATE dx

SELECT Drive,
    convert(DECIMAL(10, 2), TotalSize) AS "TotalSize(GB)",
    convert(DECIMAL(10, 2), FreeSize) AS "FreeSize(GB)"
FROM #DriveInfo
ORDER BY drive

DROP TABLE #Dletter

DROP TABLE #size

DROP TABLE #DriveInfo
```

Comment: The question states that he cannot shell out.

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you run

```
exec master..xp_fixeddrives
```

Comment: xp_fixeddrives will give me the root drive free space.  What I'm really looking for is the free space on the LUN, which is the mount point.

Comment: I see, not sure how you would do it without running cmdshell

Comment: To Clarify, 

drive    free
-----    ----
C        6260
Z        971

Z is the host drive for multiple mount points.  I want the space left on those mount points.

Answer (score 0):

> "fsutil" output has changed over the period of time. Hence, the old code throws error.
>
> Here is the modified version.

```
-------------------------------
--Disk Space using FSUtil
-------------------------------

DECLARE @Drive TINYINT,
    @SQL VARCHAR(200)

SET @Drive = 97 --ASCII VALUE

DECLARE @Drives TABLE
    (
        Drive CHAR(1),
        Info VARCHAR(200),
        starting int,
        lengthstr int
    )

WHILE @Drive <= 122
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''fsutil volume diskfree ' + CHAR(@Drive) + ':'''

        INSERT  @Drives
            (
                Info
            )
        EXEC    (@SQL)

        UPDATE  @Drives
        SET Drive = CHAR(@Drive)
        WHERE   Drive IS NULL

        SET @Drive = @Drive + 1
    END

update @Drives
set  starting = charindex(':',Info,1)+1
, lengthstr = case when charindex('(',Info,1)>0 then charindex('(',Info,1) - charindex(':',Info,1) - 1 else len (Info) end


-- Show the expected output
SELECT [Server],Drive,TotalGB,FreeGB,convert(numeric(18,1),FreeGB*100/TotalGB) as Percent_Free
From(
SELECT top 100 percent  @@servername as [Server],UPPER(Drive) AS Drive,

        convert(numeric(18,1),
        (SUM(CASE WHEN Info LIKE 'Total # of bytes%:%'
        THEN CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Info, starting, lengthstr), CHAR(13), '') AS BIGINT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIGINT) END))/1024/1024/1024.0
        )
        AS TotalGB,

        convert(numeric(18,1),
        SUM(CASE WHEN Info LIKE 'Total # of free bytes%:%'
        THEN CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Info, starting, lengthstr), CHAR(13), '') AS BIGINT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIGINT) END)/1024/1024/1024.0)
        AS FreeGB,

        convert(numeric(18,1),
        SUM(CASE WHEN Info LIKE 'Total # of avail free bytes%:%'
        THEN CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Info, starting, lengthstr), CHAR(13), '') AS BIGINT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIGINT) END)/1024/1024/1024.0)
        AS AvailFreeGB

FROM    (
            SELECT  Drive, Info,starting,lengthstr
            FROM    @Drives
            WHERE   Info LIKE 'Total # of %'
        ) AS d
GROUP BY    Drive
ORDER BY    Drive
) A

GO
```